# Ad-ID (IDFA) and Google Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am currently developing an App for iOS for iPhone with Google AdMob intergrated within it. I implementetd other Firebase functions like Firebase Messaging, because I am planning to push notifications.

As stated by Google, Google uses the Apple IDFA and conforms to its guidelines. Therefore, I assume by submitting this App, I should select IDFA.

But in the same time, I am planning to bring the exact same app without Ads, but still with Google Framework being integrated within it, because, as I said, I am planning to push notifications.

My question is: should I remove the Google AdMob interface before submitting the Ad-Free app? If no need to do so, should I select IDFA on submission? If it has to be removed, what and from where should I exactly remove?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

In the Ad-Free version, I removed the complete framework and reinstalled it using "pod install" but this time installing only 'Firbase', 'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/Messaging" without AdMob.

My app got accepted without selecting IDFA upon submission.